Draw Boundary Lines Based on Local Highest Values
I am using terra to explore areas of deforestation. I have two rasters, the first contains the area of deforestation by year of tree cover. The second raster is the remaining tree cover. I am currently using the function terra::distance() to calculate how far any pixel of my forest is from an edge.
Here is an example, r represents the forest disturbance layers and dist represents the forest canopy distance from an edge.
library(terra)

disturbance <- c(10,250,300,301,302,336,400,500,600)

r <- rast(ncols=36, nrows=18, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
r[disturbance[1:2]] <- 1
r[disturbance[3:6]] <- 2
r[disturbance[7:9]] <- 3
plot(r, col =c("red", "blue", "purple"))

dist <- rast(ncols=36, nrows=18, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
dist[disturbance] <- 1
dist <- distance(r) 
dist <- ifel(dist == 0, NA, dist)
plot(dist, add=T)

I think the next step would be to treat the results from the distance function as elevation with the largest values (ie., furthest from forest edge) as the ridge lines. I would like to be able to create polygons that run along the local highest pixel values, similar to plot(as.contour(dist), add = TRUE). This way I would then be able to quantify all the raster pixels that fall within each boundary.

One approach is the following:
First calculate the distance from the forest edges using the distance function. Then create contour lines from the distance raster using as.contour and convert the contour lines to polygons using as.polygons. Finally convert the raster r to points for easy spatial operations and use the intersect function to find points within each polygon and aggregate the points to count how many fall within each polygon.
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(exactextractr)

disturbance <- c(10, 250, 300, 301, 302, 336, 400, 500, 600)

r <- rast(ncols=36, nrows=18, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
r[disturbance[1:2]] <- 1
r[disturbance[3:6]] <- 2
r[disturbance[7:9]] <- 3
plot(r, col=c("red", "blue", "purple"))

dist <- rast(ncols=36, nrows=18, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
dist[disturbance] <- 1
dist <- distance(r)
dist <- ifel(dist == 0, NA, dist)
plot(dist, add=TRUE)

contour_levels <- seq(min(values(dist), na.rm = TRUE), max(values(dist), na.rm = TRUE), by = 10)
contours <- as.contour(dist, levels = contour_levels)
plot(contours, add = TRUE)

contour_polygons <- as.polygons(contours)
contour_polygons_list <- lapply(1:length(contour_polygons), function(i) {
  st_as_sf(contour_polygons[i])
})
contour_polygons_sf <- do.call(rbind, contour_polygons_list)

print(st_geometry(contour_polygons_sf))

plot(contour_polygons_sf)
pixel_count <- exact_extract(dist, contour_polygons_sf, 'count')
print(pixel_count)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(xyFromCell(r, 1:ncell(r)), values(r)))
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "value")
df$distance <- values(dist)
df <- na.omit(df)

ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = distance), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_sf(data = contour_polygons_sf, fill = NA, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "viridis") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Forest Canopy Distance from Edge with Contours",
       fill = "Distance")


which will return the following plots:



You can also print the contours:
Geometry set for 8 features 
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -174.8908 ymin: -74.89079 xmax: 174.8908 ymax: 44.89079
Projected CRS: PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 1N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-177,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]],
        ID["EPSG",16001]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
First 5 geometries:
POLYGON ((-155 -42.12762, -162.1276 -35, -164.8...
POLYGON ((-75 -22.12762, -82.12762 -15, -84.890...
POLYGON ((125 -62.12762, 117.8724 -55, 115.1092...
POLYGON ((145 7.872382, 137.8724 15, 135.1092 2...
POLYGON ((-165 -47.20779, -167.2078 -45, -173.2...


for the aggregate function, how would you turn contour polygons into a list?

I improved my answer
